# Convert fixed and byte* from c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following code in c# and would like to convert it in VB.NET. I'm not sure what `fixed` and `byte*` are and how they can be converted. The telerik converter does not provide any help on this.

```
fixed (byte* ptrShapeBufferPtr = pointerInfo.PtrShapeBuffer)
{
    mDeskDupl.GetFramePointerShape(
           frameInfo.PointerShapeBufferSize, 
           (IntPtr)ptrShapeBufferPtr, 
           out pointerInfo.BufferSize, 
           out pointerInfo.ShapeInfo);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: that is a pointer to a pointer, **as far as i know** VB.NET doesn't support pointers.

Comment: This is unsafe code, which VB doesn't allow.  It looks like the code is trying to interface with a C++ method.  What I tend to do in these situations is write a managed C++ wrapper around the native methods, basically giving the C++ a safe .NET interface.  I can then call it from VB or any other .NET language.

Comment: `GCHandle.Alloc(..., GCHandleType.Pinned)`, `GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject`. I mean, if you *must*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since VB.NET doesn't support pointers you have to use an `IntPtr` instead. The most simple way to do so is to mark the object as not getting Garbage Collected using a [**`GCHandle`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you use the [**`AddrOfPinnedObject` method**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject(v=vs.110).aspx) to get its pointer as an `IntPtr`.

```vb
Dim handle As GCHandle

Try
    handle = GCHandle.Alloc(pointerInfo.PtrShapeBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim ptrShapeBufferPtr As IntPtr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()

    mDeskDupl.GetFramePointerShape(frameInfo.PointerShapeBufferSize, ptrShapeBufferPtr, pointerInfo.BufferSize, pointerInfo.ShapeInfo)
Finally
    If handle.IsAllocated = True Then handle.Free()
End Try
```

Note that this is a more of a quick and dirty solution. `GCHandle` isn't expected to be used like this, but it works and is (AFAIK) still okay to use. There are other (longer) ways of doing this which were more specifically designed for these kinds of things.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET : Ok, so the original type was a byte array. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @HansPassant : Stop making my answers for me. ;)

Comment: @alwaysVBNET : Took a little time because I'm writing from my phone, but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Don't forget `Try .. Finally`. You don't want to leave GC handles lying around.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Didn't think of that, thanks! **EDIT:** Fixed.

Comment: @alwaysVBNET : Updated again to add `Try/Finally` like Jeroen suggested. Glad I (or more correctly: we) could help!

Comment: And don't forget to add a comment apologising for this to anyone who has to read this sort of code in VB.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas : What do you mean??

Comment: @DaveDoknjas : Are you referring to the fact that this is more of a quick and dirty solution and not an optimal one?

Comment: @VisualVincent: Sorry - disconnected for a few days.  I mean that it's just not 'expected' code - it should be documented to indicate this (maybe 'apologising' was too harsh).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas : Better? :)